# How to insert array values into SugarCRM using soapUI

Tags: soapui, sugarcrm

I am able to log into SugarCRM (with its SOAP call) using soapUI:

```xml
<user_auth xsi:type="sug:user_auth">
    <user_name xsi:type="xsd:string">admin</user_name>
    <password xsi:type="xsd:string">21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3</password>
<user_auth>
```

Doing that, I get a session id (among other things). But now I want to add some data into the Leads module. The xml looks like this:

```xml
<sug:set_entry soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <session xsi:type="xsd:string">5bhvqlqgb9a0vi70e73l053m92</session>
    <module_name xsi:type="xsd:string">Leads</module_name>
    <name_value_list xsi:type="sug:name_value_list" soapenc:arrayType="sug:name_value[]"/>
</sug:set_entry>
```

I've populated 2 of the three required fields, **session** and **module_name**. How do I populate the 3rd, **name_value_list**? As an example, let's assume that I only want to add `first_name` and `last_name` of the Lead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works with SugarCRM 5.x. so it will properly also work with 6.x.

```xml
<sug:set_entry soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <session xsi:type="xsd:string">xx</session>
 <module_name xsi:type="xsd:string">Leads</module_name>
 <name_value_list xsi:type="sug:name_value_list" soapenc:arrayType="sug:name_value[]">
    <item xsi:type="tns:name_value">
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">first_name</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">test</value>
    </item>
    <item xsi:type="tns:name_value">
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">last_name</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">test2</value>
    </item>
 </name_value_list>
</sug:set_entry>
```